# Custom Voice Commands for Google Maps Navigation for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I am creating a mobile application which requires the user to click on a button and enable voice commands to guide him / her to their destination.

The client wants me to give custom voice commands for directions. These voice commands can be used as alerts for the user or can be used as prompts to guide the user if the user is going to the wrong direction.

The user creates his / her own custom start and destination points on the map. Thus, the voice commands should be able to guide him or her on the direction the user selects.

Can i tweek the voice commands on google maps the way i want to?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this problem? If you did, it would be great if you share the solution.